# Output should return top 5 application name based on count property which present ImageDetails object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
data = {
"ImageDetails": [
    {
        "application": "unknownApp,
        "count": 107757,        
    },
    {
        "application": "app6",
        "count": 1900,
    },
    {
        "application": "app8",
        "count": 0,
    },
    {
        "application": "app3",
        "count": 100,
    },
    {
        "application": "app9"
        "count": 0,
    },
    {
        "application": "app1"
        "count": 0,
    },
    {     
        "application": "app10"
        "count": 0,
    },
    {
        "application": "app7",
        "count": 0,
    }
  ]
}
```

when i subscribed api i am getting data as above.

Output should return top 5 application name based on count
property ImageDetails.
expected Output : [unknownApp,app6,app3,app8,app9]

Comment: So you want to sort the data based on the count and get 5 with the most count?

Comment: Yes and i wants to return application names of highest individual count

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting object property by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values)

Comment: [Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) based on the `count` value and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) first 5 items. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37607084/11566161)

Answer (score 1):

Your data is invalid but I fixed it by adding missing quotes and comma

But if the data from the api is malformed you probably have to ask the data provider

[`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) is used to deep copy the array so when you modify the copied array the original won't be changed

You can [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the data based on the count then [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get top 5

Then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the data to get only the app names

```js
const apps = data.ImageDetails

const sortedApps = structuredClone(apps).sort((a, b) => {
  return b.count - a.count
})

const top5Apps = sortedApps.slice(0, 5)

const top5AppNames = top5Apps.map(app => app.application)

console.log(top5AppNames)
```

```html
<script>
  // Data here to show the js code on top
  const data = {
    "ImageDetails": [{
        "application": "unknownApp",
        "count": 107757,
      },
      {
        "application": "app6",
        "count": 1900,
      },
      {
        "application": "app8",
        "count": 0,
      },
      {
        "application": "app3",
        "count": 100,
      },
      {
        "application": "app9",
        "count": 0,
      },
      {
        "application": "app1",
        "count": 0,
      },
      {
        "application": "app10",
        "count": 0,
      },
      {
        "application": "app7",
        "count": 0,
      }
    ]
  }
</script>
```